# When is a windows service considered "started"

Tags: windows, service

We have a process that is executed as a windows service,
This process serves as an interface server processing incoming messages, transforms them and sends them out to another interface.

it is a rather heavy process, it needs to load a lot of things into memory and that takes some time (few minutes).
due to its nature, when we start it using its windows service, it remains in "starting" status for a very long time (sometimes more than 20 minutes)
even when we can see the process already works and process messages just fine (going by its logs).

so the question is - when is a service considered "starting" and when is it considered "started"? based on what factors?

Comment: Each Windows service reports its status to the service control manager using the SetServiceStatus function.  The service is considered "started" when it tells Windows that it is started, it is entirely up to the programmer when that happens.  (If you are using the ServiceBase class provided by the .NET framework, the service reports that it is started as soon as the OnStart function returns.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting status finish when onstart is completed.

You should write starting code after onstart event.

```
puclic class Service1
{
        private Timer timer = new Timer();

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            this.timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
            this.timer.Interval = 1 * 1000; // 1 second
            this.timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.timer.Enabled = false; // OnElapsedTime run only one time

            // Write your code
        }
 }
```

Comment: You are assuming that the OP is talking about a .NET service.  That's OK, but you should explicitly say so.

Comment: Thank you! it was indeed a .NET service, i should've mentioned that.
I do see that we have this OnStart override in the code, and now i see what areas to look for in terms of consuming most of the time.